# How can you upload an image/jpeg file to a presigned url on s3, while sending Content-Type multipart/form-data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, http, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I may have some misunderstanding this works. Essentially I would like to upload images to a presigned url generated via S3. Currently I am sending POST requests with the following headers:

```
      "Content-Type": 'image/jpeg',
      "file": {
        uri: some_image,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: `some_image.jpeg`
      }
```

So this works. However I'm finding the upload very very slow. The images are 2-3 MBs each. On wifi it's much quicker but on a mobile network, it can take up to 30 seconds. I've read changing the Content-Type to multipart/form-data will help accelerate the upload. However when I modify it to `Content-Type: form-data`, the metadata on s3 will be set to `Content-Type: form-data`. But I want the `Content-Type: form-data` to be `image/jpeg` as this image will be served on the internet. If not set to `Content-Type: image/jpeg`, the browser will simply download the file to a directory.

The below doesn't work as the metadata on the image on S3 has metadata Content-Type: multipart/form-data

```
      "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data',
      "file": {
        uri: some_image,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: `some_image.jpeg`
      }
```

I'm using React. My axios function looks like this.

```
export default function HTTP({ method, url, data, params, headers }) {  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
    const query = {
      method: method,
      url: url,
    }
    if (params) {
      query.params = params
    }
    if (headers != null) {
      query.headers = headers;
    }
    if (data) {
      query.data = data;
    }   
    axios({...query, timeout: 30000}).then(function (response) {
      resolve(response);
    })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error) {
          NavigatorService.navigate('Back');
        }
        reject(error)

      })
  })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: where you create a form-data? just you mention "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'.  you need to convert the file objects into form-data.

Comment: multipart as you use it is the type of the protocol. If you are passing to axios a stream it automatically uses the multipart protocol technique, and you can keep the contentType of your presigned url 'image/jpeg'

Comment: any luck? having a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70490650/403-when-upload-file-to-s3-bucket-using-axios

Answer (score 0):

Hi **@readdit55** you need to create form data like.

```
Example:
       headers: 
           "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data',
       body: 
          createFormData({
             'uri': some_image,
             'type': 'image/jpeg',
             'name'': `some_image.jpeg`
          });

**Method to create form data:**
       const createFormData = (objects) => {
             const data = new FormData();
             Object.keys(objects).forEach((key,Index)=>{
                 data.append(key, body[key]);
             });
             return data;
       })
```